# System.Web.HttpException Error

Tags: c#, file-upload

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class Expt : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    protected void Bttnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       FileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath("~/img//"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+FileUpload1.FileName));

    }
}
```

> Exception Details: `System.Web.HttpException: ~/img//1/1/2011 1:47:52 PMWinter.jpg` is not a valid virtual path.

Comment: Friend we are not here to fix your silly problems. BTW colon (:) is not valid for file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var path = MapPath("~/img");
var datePart = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss-");
var filename = Path.Combine(path, datePart + FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filename);
```

Comment: What needs to be included to Use the Path as class

Comment: @jagdeep, the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class is defined in the `System.IO` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Three possibilities jump out at me.

- `:` isn't a valid character in filenames on Windows systems.
- Directory `~/img//1/1/` doesn't exist.
- It doesn't like the double forward slash.

Comment: @ Pradeep Thanks i got it because  BTW colon (:) is not valid for file names.